# Checkstyle: access variable names?

Tags: java, variables, text, checkstyle

We have a standard that variable names must be spelled different (not just case).  For example, this is illegal:

```
int INDEX = 0;
int index = 0;
```

I am trying write a Checkstyle extension to support this, but `ast.getText()` is returning "variable_def" instead of the actual variable name.  How do I do it?  Thanks.

```
package check;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.FullIdent;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;

public class VariableSpelling extends Check {
    private ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();

    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[] { TokenTypes.VARIABLE_DEF };
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when a node is found
     */
    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast) {
        String var = ast.getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I found the problem.  You can't get the text of a VARIABLE_DEF.  You have to drill down to the IDENT...then get the text on that.

Comment: Can you please update the code with the solution? I am facing a similar problem, and as I'm new to this CheckStyle, it would be helpful to see where to make the changes...